# How long does it take until a gmail account is available again to register?

Tags: gmail

I have a gmail account whose password has been lost years ago. I don't know the security questions' answers and the telephone reset number has been since cancelled. How long does it take until the account is permanently deleted from gmail and I will be able to create another with the same name again?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming and should probably be asked to Google directly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Google support.  You may have more luck at http://webapps.stackexchange.com but check their FAQ first.

Comment: You should ask this to the gmail helpdesk. This is a programming q&a site.

Comment: THis may be somewhat relevant: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/does-a-gmail-account-ever-expire

Comment: What makes you think that Google is *ever* going to delete your account and make it available for public registration again?  That seems like a grossly irresponsible thing for them to do, I doubt it would ever happen.

Comment: @David yahoo did it a few years ago. And yes, it was a terrible idea.

Comment: @basher: Sounds like a compelling reason never to use Yahoo! for email services then.  Imagine the privacy concerns of people registering identical addresses used by other people.

Comment: @David Yes I know. I imagined when I first read they were going to do it...then it became reality: http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-24283179 "I can gain access to their Pandora account [online radio] but I won't. I can gain access to their Facebook account, but I won't. I know their name, address and phone number. I know where their child goes to school. I know the last four digits of their social security number. I know they had an eye doctor's appointment last week and I was just invited to their friend's wedding."

Comment: I think that the accusations that my question is "Gmail support" and "nothing to do with programming (thus must be closed)" are totally unfounded since there are other questions about Gmail in StackOverflow that are also support and don't have anything to do with programming (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394608/does-gmail-limit-receiving-multiple-nearly-identical-messages-into-the-same-acco?rq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520042/gmail-sync-on-android-phone?rq=1)). Let alone the number of support questions about other projects.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere that the accounts will expire after 9 months of inactivity. This was from one of the software engineers. If it's been a couple of years I would definitely try contacting them to see if they can release it for re-registration.